# regarding security concerns, are browser providers excusable for allowing cross site cookies?

Tags: security, cookies, cross-browser, standards

Regarding security concerns, are browser-providers excusable for allowing cross-site cookies ?
Does any important use of it do justify the existance of this dangerous mechanism?

See [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475141/1767316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Webmasters can ask (modern) browser to only sent cookies when first-party with the SameSite attribute:

> Set-Cookie: key=value; HttpOnly; SameSite=strict

https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/

Beware, it's possible that when arriving on the website from another, cookies will not be sent.