# Is this method safe to use for login and ANTI-CSRF

Tags: java, php, security, csrf

i have a question, im doing an mobile app with java and on the back end php.
On the back end php i send the email+password and validate, if their is a match i generate a unique session token(encrypted sha256 with a salt that is changed every 2h) and send it back to mobile app(java) and store it. Can this token be used for protection anti csrf and use to verify if the user is logged(checking in back end if the token is in db with the email associate)?

i will give an example of the code(i cant reproduce 100% of the code bcs i work OOP and i need to drop all the clasess

page 1: login

```
$password = password_hash(...); // encrypt the password received
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from accounts where email='{$email}'") // i know is sql vulnerable, but on my project i doing this with protection
....
if(password_verify($password,$passwordFromDb))
{
  $sessionID = hash("sha256", ...) // here i use an unique salt with a random num(random_int) and some other fields
  $mysqli->query("delete from sessions where email='{$email}'");
  $mysqli->query("insert into sessions (email,session) values('{$email}','{$sessionID}')");
}
```

page 2: do some stuff

```
$email = $_post["email"]; 
$sessionID = $_post["session"];
$result = $mysqli->query(...); // select sessions with that email
...
if(hash_equals($sessionID,$sessionIDfromDB))
{
   //is ok, he can do some change with the acc or anything less
   //but not stuff for security(ex: change password, delete account, etc that need high level security)
}
```

is the code above secured for csrf vulnerability or something else?

Comment: First of all this site is for questions that need to provide some codes, answer to your question. use `password_verify()` instead of `sha256` dont send email and password by email for validation, which will return like `etc=password&etc=email` in url and that is a security risk. use tokens for validation. if you add your codes in question, you will get better answers in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kaderkandar Hi, first of all, your answer doesnt help me at all. What email?What validation?I didnt said that i encrypt password with sha256, i said i encrypt the token with sha256.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not use session ID as XSRF token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968074/why-not-use-session-id-as-xsrf-token)